# AWS Lambda with API Gateway Proxy using PHP code deployed using docker el2 runtime returns base64 instead of binary image

Tags: php, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-lambda-containers

So we have a legacy code which returns a gif image, running on-prem. Recently decided to, migrate the same  aws lambda using al2 docker image. I've used the [aws sample code on github](https://github.com/aws-samples/php-examples-for-aws-lambda/tree/master/0.7-PHP-Lambda-functions-with-Docker-container-images) and modified the boostrap to suit my needs. API Gateway is used as the proxy in front of the lambda. I have followed the exact pattern [given here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/lambda-proxy-binary-media.html), encoding as base64 and isBase64Encoded as true and content-type as image/gif etc.  Testing locally and checking the Cloudwatch logs, I can clearly see the base64 and the json formatted correctly. But on the chrome browser the image is not displayed, and when I saved the preview of the image dot using chrome's devtools it's in Base64. API Gateway  is not converting it back to binary. I ma using the APIGW HTTP api. Note: *I've successfully used **Bref** and it works fine, but our Infosec and devops wants to use docker images from aws. I thought I'll give it a try - came this far, but stuck at this frustrating issue.*

The PHP sample code is below (I am not a php expert, it's the first time I am working on PHP code, but lots of experience in Java, C#, node etc so please excuse for any mistakes):

**1. Code which converts the binary to base64**

[image: Code which converts the binary to base64]

**2. Part of the bootstrap code**

[image: Part of the bootstrap code]

**3. Cloudwatch logs**

[image: Cloudwatch logs]

**4. The Chrome response headers**

[image: The Chrome response headers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the issue. It was an upper case in the `IsBase64Encoded`. After changing it to `isBase64Encoded` (lower case i), it worked. Never thought it was case sensitive!